# What makes an input vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

I've been reading about XSS and I made a simple form with a text and submit input, but when I execute `<script>alert();</script>` on it, nothing happens, the server gets that string and that's all.

What do I have to do for make it vulnerable?? (then I'll learn what I shouldn't do hehe)

Cheers.

Comment: Are you using any server side language?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Indeed just let the server output it so that the input string effectively get embedded in HTML source which get returned to the client.

PHP example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><title>XSS test</title></head>
    <body>
        <form><input type="text" name="xss"><input type="submit"></form>
        <p>Result: <?= $_GET['xss'] ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSP example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><title>XSS test</title></head>
    <body>
        <form><input type="text" name="xss"><input type="submit"></form>
        <p>Result: ${param.xss}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you can redisplay the value in the input elements, that's also often seen:

```
<input type="text" name="xss" value="<?= $_GET['xss'] ?>">
```

resp.

```
<input type="text" name="xss" value="${param.xss}">
```

This way "weird" attack strings like `"/><script>alert('xss')</script><br class="` will work because the server will render it after all as

```
<input type="text" name="xss" value=""/><script>alert('xss')</script><br class="">
```

XSS-prevention solutions are among others [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) for PHP and JSP respectively. Those will replace among others `<`, `>` and `"` by `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&quot;` so that enduser input doesn't end up to be literally embedded in HTML source but instead just got displayed as it was entered.

Answer (score 23):

Have the server output the input back to the client.

Comment: I read "Having the server output the input back to the client.", and thought wow, that's the most simplest, and dead-on answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

You should "inject" the script. So if you have a text-input, you should put in the form:

```
" /> <script>alert();</script>
```

This way you first close the attribute of the existing HTML and then inject your own code. The idea is to escape out the quotes.

Comment: That's not what he's asking.  He knows how to perform the attack, he's asking what makes an input vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

Google made a really awesome tutorial that covers XSS and other security vulnerabilities [here](https://google-gruyere.appspot.com/). It can help you understand how these issues are exploited in real applications.

Answer (score 1):

Three simple things:

1. If you're not outputting untrusted data to the page at some point there is no opportunity for XSS
2. All your untusted data (forms, querystrings, headers, etc) should be validated against a whitelist to ensure it's within an acceptable range
3. All your output to the screen should be endcoded with an appropriate library (ie Anti-XSS for .NET) onto the appropriate language (HTML, CSS, JS, etc).

More info with examples in [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 2: Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-2.html).