# Which is the difference about writing "&lt;" and "<" in the database?

Tags: character-encoding

I have a database that's encoded in latin1_swedish_ci. I'd like to know what's the difference between inserting `&lt;` and `<` in the database?

Answer (score 5):

It are not different character encodings. The `&lt;` is just an XML-escaped form of `<` which is usually used to prevent it from being interpreted as start of a XML (or HTML) element. This prevention is often used as part of [XSS prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). This is normally applied when user-controlled data is about to be inlined in HTML output and not when user-controlled input is about to be stored in the DB.

So, if you're seeing `&lt;` instead of `<` in the DB while it should have been a `<`, then it can only mean that some XML/HTML-escaping logic is running at the wrong moment.

#### See also:

- [What makes an input vulnerable to XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905886/what-makes-an-input-vulnerable-to-xss/2906297#2906297)

Comment: For example, in usernames and posts in a forum, it's more correct to have '<' or '& lt;' ?

Comment: Keeping the original user input is correct. As answered, you should only escape it when it's about to be inlined in HTML output and not when it's about to be stored in the DB. The `<` character is completely harmless in the DB. It's only harmful in XML/HTML, because it represents the start of an element, such as `<script>`. For the DB part, you should only worry about SQL injection attack vectors such as quotes, because it represents the start and end of a SQL column value.

Comment: Sorry I'm not good with such things. I'm using vbulletin, so I've no control overs escaping. I've converted the db from phpbb, and now I've some problems with users because phpbb parsed correctly `&amp;lt` showing -> `<`, while vbulletin shows `&lt`. Is it safe if I manually change `&amp;lt` in `<` in the database?

Comment: You're only safe if user-controlled input is escaped during generating HTML output. See also the "See also" link for an answer with a concrete example of how XSS works.

Answer (score 2):

`&lt;` is a [HTML character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references) that refers to the character `<`. The difference is that `&lt;` takes four characters space while `<` takes only one character. That’s all regarding databases.

Comment: For example, in usernames and posts in a forum, it's more correct to have '<' or '& lt;' ?

Comment: You should store the data in the database as is and only apply the required encoding. Similarly, when this data is printed in an HTML document, depending on the context, you are required to encoding the data using HTML character references.

Comment: Sorry I'm not good with such things. I'm using vbulletin, so I've no control overs escaping. I've converted the db from phpbb, and now I've some problems with users because phpbb parsed correctly `&amp;lt` showing -> `<`, while vbulletin shows `&lt`. Is it safe if I manually change `&amp;lt` in `<` in the database?

Comment: @DanieleImpagliazzo That depends on what phpbb does with the stored value. If it properly escapes them on every output, it’s fine to restore the original `<`. Otherwise, you should keep the stored values. You could check that by registering a new user or changing a user’s name to something `foo<bar` and check whether that get’s printed as is or if it get’s printed as `foo&lt;bar`.

Answer (score 1):

The first is an HTML entity - in other words, that's how you would escape a `<` if you wanted to output one in HTML. The second is the literal character.

In general, your database should not include content that assumes a particular output format (HTML/XML, in this case). For instance, if that content were to be available in a plain text format, you'd want to show `<`, not `&lt;`. So you should store `<` in the database, and escape to `&lt;` when rendering for HTML output.

Comment: For example, in the database, in usernames and posts is it more correct to have '<' or '& lt;' ? I'm using vbulletin.

Comment: I'd say that user names and posts should be stored using `<` and encoded accordingly, but that depends on the vBulletin implementation. If all is working correctly regarding how it is rendered in the post, then however it is being stored in the database is correct for that application.