# Will browser execute script inside the input value?

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core, google-chrome, xss

After user submit a html form, on post back when browser renders a page, if one of the input field value is `script` tag with function surrounded by quote, will the browser ever execute the script and is it considered as XSS attack?
For Example:

```
  <form>    
      <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="<script>alert('test');</script>">    
   </form>
```

My quick test doesn't seems to execute the script. (Why?)
DAST scanner is reporting this as XSS issue

My [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998610/asp-net-core-not-encoding-input-value-on-post-back)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes an input vulnerable to XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905886/what-makes-an-input-vulnerable-to-xss)